# Check if a String contains something between quotes

Tags: c#

I am writing I application where the user can input a document. Then I read each line of the Document and work further with the attributes.
In Each line we have 5 attributes. The Attributes get separated by a semicolon.

For Example:
If a Attribute have a semicolo in his name the user will input the attribute then so in the Document:
"test;with"

Now I want to check if the attribute is in quotes and ignore it. How would you guys do it?

Here is the important code snippet:

```
foreach (string line in lines)
{
    if (line == "")
    {
        continue;
    }

    if (lineindex > lines.Length)
    {
        continue;
    }
    lineindex++;
    string[] words = line.Split(';'); // i would add here a if statement
    foreach (string word in words)
    {
        count++; 
        if (count == 6)
        {
            attribNewValue = "";
            maskName = "";
            actualAttrbValue = "";
            actualAttrbName = "";
            attribNameForEdit = "";
            count = 1;
            maskexist = false;
            attribexist = false;
        }
        else
        {
            // Or here to each word
            if (count == 1)
            {
                maskName = word;
            }
            else if (count == 2)
            {
                actualAttrbName = word;
            }
            else if (count == 3)
            {
                actualAttrbValue = word;
            }
            else if (count == 4)
            {
                attribNameForEdit = word;
            }
            else if (count == 5)
            {
                attribNewValue = word;
            }       
        }
```

Thank you in advance!

Comment: please code review your own code you are missing 2 closing `}` one for the inner foreach  loop and another for the outer foreach loop also when you use the split function, the values in the string[] would be checked you should really think about the process and what it is you're wanting to do and refactor this code..

Comment: yes i have not added the whole code, i have written thats its only the code snippet:)

Comment: Learn regular expressions, this is trivial.

Comment: How you would do it with Regular expression, i dont want to replace something? I want that it got ignored?

Comment: You could write your own Split function that ignores the separator, when inside quotes.

Comment: Hello Alexandru, at least i had made it with a own method. But i though there would be an easier way. Would be greate if there is an easier way and i can lern something new:)

Answer (score 4):

You can use `String.IndexOf(char value)` and `String.LastIndexOf(char value)` to determine this:

```
string[] words;
int semicolonIndex = line.IndexOf(';');
int firstQuoteIndex = line.IndexOf('"');
int lastQuoteIndex = line.LastIndexOf('"');

if (firstQuoteIndex == lastQuoteIndex)
    continue;

if (semicolonIndex > firstQuoteIndex && semicolonIndex < lastQuoteIndex)
    words = line.Split(';');
```

More information:

`IndexOf()`: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.indexof(v=vs.110).aspx

`LastIndexOf()`: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.lastindexof(v=vs.110).aspx

As one of the comments mentioned, this can also be achieved with regular expressions in far fewer lines of code than my solution, but gauging your skill level (no offense) I think this is easier for you to read, understand, and get started with. Regardless of whether or not there is a more elegant solution, string manipulation is a pretty basic things and it would be good to familiarize yourself with all of the methods on the `String` class as found here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string_methods(v=vs.110).aspx

Lastly, while this is purely developer-preference, I would recommend using `String.Empty` instead of `""`. This makes your code's intentions more explicit to other readers / developers. By using `""`, one might ask "Well did they MEAN to use an empty string, or did they make a typo and aren't assigning what they think they're assigning?" By using `String.Empty`, there is no question that you meant to use an empty string. So I would do `if (line == String.Empty) continue;` instead of `if (line == "") continue;`